# How to avoid ajax reload when you click the back button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a page that used Ajax to generate the a list of result.  Then there is a link to click to another detail page.  When I'm at the detail page, and click the back button.  The list of results page will reload again.  Is there anyway to stop the ajax to reload again and cache the result.  Also is there anyway to cache the position also.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

A few projects I had bookmarked regarding the AJAX/back button management

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

https://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin

Regarding your second question, if your browser supports local DB you may cache the result there. The following project provide a uniform API across browsers.

https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js

https://github.com/alexmng/sticky

Position can also be stored in the localDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can save state by changing the `window.location.hash` property. The hash is the only part of the URL that you can change and not force a reload of the URL.

`window.location.hash = 'some-id';` will translate into your URL looking like this: `index.html#some-id`.

You can then get the hash when the page loads and set the UI to the proper state:

```
if (window.location.hash == 'some-id') {
    //setup UI for `some-id` identifier
}
```

Comment: I think the question wasn't about reloading the url, but whether the javascript state of a page can be cached and resumed when the user goes back to that page - something that would require browser support, so: do browsers support it?

Comment: Yeah it would have been a good idea for me to put a notice on my answer. This isn't a direct answer but an option that might have been overlooked. I was thinking that with this you could store information in a cookie (or localStorage/sessionStorage) and retrieve the info based on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Store your data with a timestamp of some sort. Check to see if you have stored data and that it's not older than you would like it to be. If it's older, fetch new data. If not use the stored data.

(it's not mozilla specific)

http://caniuse.com/#search=local%20storage

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new HTML5 LocalStorage system to build a cache. Here's a link: http://playground.html5rocks.com/#localstorage